# Does Alea GPU support the new GeForce cards

Tags: c#, aleagpu

I have a GTX 1060 card, when trying to run the [AleaGPU examples](https://github.com/quantalea/AleaGPUTutorial) I get the following error:

**`{"Unknown arch: sm61"}`**

Does AleaGPU not support these cards?

Here is the output from the C++ deviceQuery program found in the CUDA toolkit:

```
Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce GTX 1060 6GB"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          8.0 / 8.0
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    6.1
  Total amount of global memory:                 6144 MBytes (6442450944 bytes)
  (10) Multiprocessors, (128) CUDA Cores/MP:     1280 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            1709 MHz (1.71 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             4004 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              192-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 1572864 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(131072), 2D=(131072, 65536), 3D=(16384, 16384, 16384)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(32768), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(32768, 32768), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 65536
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 2 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  CUDA Device Driver Mode (TCC or WDDM):         WDDM (Windows Display Driver Model)
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 66 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 8.0, CUDA Runtime Version = 8.0, NumDevs = 1, Device0 = GeForce GTX 1060 6GB
```

Comment: see this link:http://quantalea.com/static/app/tutorial/getting_started/first_alea_gpu_program.html. Questions are directed to here.

Comment: click on the link ask a question, from that page. Then look at the other questions tagged aleagpu, this question is inline with others on this topic. I not sure if closing questions is really helping anyone here.

Comment: @screig that doesn't mean its on topic. you have to read the [faq] or the [helpcenter]

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d#.vf47hhmap

Comment: the only purpose (of your (stuartd) interpretation of some idiotic rule) they are serving seems to be to allow people who have no subject matter experience to gain idiotic points at the expense at people usefully trying to exchange relevant programming knowledge. For example do you have any experience or knowledge of GPU programming?  Why are you even commenting here?

Comment: On his blog, Jeff Atwood, co-founder of Stack Overflow, explains the meaning of the word trolling:
[A] classic troll [can be described as follows:]
1. He came to generate argument.
2. He doesn’t truly care about the topic.

Comment: "whether your card is supported or not is nothing to do with GPU programming"  What planet are you living on? The reason aleagpu is failing as the it appears I cannot code software against a card with a compute capability of 6.1. So I can gpu-code against in C++ but not in C#. Stuart do you know anything about AleaGPU, if not why are you commenting here?

Comment: What makes you believe that anyone here has insight into the source code of AleaGPU? This is a community website, we help with finding/fixing issues in code you wrote. As this appears to be an issue with AleaGPU itself I'd suggest taking it up with them (they have a "Contact" page on their website). Further your attitude is less than ideal, you are yelling at people for suggesting that another website might be better suited for your question (and I don't see how we are supposed to be responsible for a website telling people to ask questions on SO)

Comment: What makes you believe that anyone here has insight into the source code of AleaGPU?....... Well the writers of the code direct users to ask questions here..........Further your attitude is less than ideal.........My attitude is fine, I am trying to get answer to a relevant question and a bunch of people who know nothing about the subject feel entitled enough to start dictating to others who should ask questions here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alea GPU beta-17 is now supporting the new Pascal architecture such as the GTX 1080.

Comment: FYI still reporting the same error using  Alea GPU beta-17. On enumerating the devices:  Cores = 'device.Cores' threw an exception of type 'System.Exception'  Message = "Unknown arch: sm61"

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Alea/3.0.0-beta18 has just been released. After some quick testing, it appears to work on my GTX 1080 with CUDA 8.0.44. Hooray! \o/ (beta 17 wouldn't work for me either)

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this problem as well when attempting to use a GTX 1080 card. It appears that the current version of AleaGPU doesn't yet support these new cards.

I emailed their support staff to ask about it and got this response: "We look into it, though currently it is not clear when we will add it. It will be not too long though, but only available in Alea GPU V3 release candidate." That was on July 8th, and I have not seen anything further since then. Hopefully something more will be posted soon.